# How to keep comments in YAML header when converting w/ pandoc

Tags: yaml, markdown, pandoc

I have a Markdown file with mixed Markdown and TeX content which is meant for being converted to PDF in the end.

I have a YAML header with something like this:

```yaml
---
title: "mytitle"
#author: [someone]
lang: "de"
date: \today
toc: false
toc-own-page: false
numbersections: false
listings: true
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{extarrows}
    \usepackage[iso,german]{isodate}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
---
```

Now I'm using pandoc to 'prettify' / format my document on every save:

`pandoc -f markdown -t markdown --standalone -Vheader-includes='' --reference-links`

This produces this output:

````yaml
---
date: "`\\today`{=tex}"
header-includes: |
  ```{=tex}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{wasysym}
  \usepackage{extarrows}
  \usepackage[iso,german]{isodate}
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  ```
lang: de
listings: true
numbersections: false
title: mytitle
toc: false
toc-own-page: false
---
````

Although I'm not happy with the `{=tex}`-blocks, I see why they might make sense and know that I could disable them with `-t markdown-raw_attribute`

But is there a way to keep the commented-out author in the YAML header block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc does not preserve the textual representation in the YAML block, keeping comments is not possible. You could prefix the unused YAML key with `_` to avoid having it influence other output.

It would be possible to keep the YAML in a separate file and to include it with `--metadata-file=...`, that would make it easy to ensure that only the text is processed.

Comment: This is valuable information and a good workaround. Thanks!